# Joining values in an arraylist

Tags: java

Say I have an arraylist a with the values:

```
a[0] = G
a[1] = B
a[2] = D
```

I was wondering, how can I create a new arraylist in java, that joins index values at random places and puts it into a new arraylist  b
So like:

```
b[0] = GB
b[1] = D
```

or

```
b[0] = G
b[1] = BD
```

or

```
b[0] = GBD
```

The order of the values is kept the same, it's  just the different combinations of the joins, and at different places over different amounts.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (pseudocode)

```
newA = new ArrayList<String>();
for (b : a) {
 if (Math.random() > 0.5) newA.add(b);
 else newA.set(previous, newA.get(previous) + b);
}
```

Comment: @dantuch @aioobe I thought it was pretty obvious this is pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the "random position" yourself, my thought would be to use something like the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public List<String> mergeAt(ArrayList<String> input, int offset) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add(StringUtils.join(input.subList(0, offset), '');
    result.add(StringUtils.join(input.subList(offset, input.size()), '');
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First merge element at index `i` with index `j`:

   ```
   yourList.set(i, yourList.get(i) + yourList.get(j));
   ```
2. Then remove element at index `j`:

   ```
   yourList.remove(j);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This satisfies all the conditions you listed above. you can adjust  `joinIndex` and `joinSize` to whatever you want and it will start at the `joinIndex` position and concatenate `joinSize` characters.

Fixed the issue with the exceeding bounds. Now it will just concat as many characters at the end as exist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TestJoiner
{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      list.add("G");
      list.add("B");
      list.add("D");
      list.add("L");
      list.add("G");
      list.add("A");

      //Get Random Int
      int joinIndex=3;
      int joinSize=2;

      //check join size, make sure it doesn't exceed bounds.   
      joinSize=(joinIndex+joinSize+1)>list.size()?list.size()-joinIndex-1:joinSize;

      //join
      for(int a=joinIndex;a<joinIndex+joinSize;a++){
         list.set(joinIndex,list.get(joinIndex)+list.get(a+1));
      }         
      //shift
      for(int c=joinIndex+1;c<list.size()-joinSize;c++){
         list.set(c,list.get(c+joinSize));
      }

      //Truncate
      list=list.subList(0,list.size()-joinSize);

      System.out.println(list);
   }
}
```

Comment: congrats on discovering ctrl+shift+f. Your mom must be proud.

Answer (score 0):

badger. Here is task solution. Just use `List<String> Shaker.shake(List<String>)` method.

**Shaker** class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Shaker {
    public static List<String> shake(List<String> sourceList) {
        Random random = new Random();

        // We'll use cloned original list
        LinkedList<String> itemsList = new LinkedList<String>(sourceList);

        // Count how much items need shaking
        int itemsToMerge = itemsList.size();

        // New generated list
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Temporary values, used in cycle
        int firstGroupItemIndex = 0;

        while (0 < itemsToMerge) {
            // Select random number of merged items
            int groupLength = random.nextInt(itemsToMerge) + 1;

            // Create inserted string value
            StringBuilder insertedValue = new StringBuilder();
            int lastGroupItemIndex = firstGroupItemIndex + groupLength;
            for (int i = firstGroupItemIndex; i < lastGroupItemIndex; i++) {
                insertedValue.append(itemsList.removeFirst());
            }

            // Add merged string value
            newList.add(insertedValue.toString());
            firstGroupItemIndex = lastGroupItemIndex;

            itemsToMerge -= groupLength;
        }

        return newList;
    }
}
```

And **Test** class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> originalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        originalList.add("G");
        originalList.add("B");
        originalList.add("C");
        originalList.add("L");
        originalList.add("G");
        originalList.add("A");

        List<String> newList = Shaker.shake(originalList);

        System.out.println("Original list: " + originalList);
        System.out.println("Shaked list: " + newList);
    }
}
```

Look at the result:

> Original list: [G, B, C, L, G, A]
>   Shaked list: [GBC, LG, A]

If you have questions about the code, I'll answer you with pleasure.
You can always find solution sources at [github.com](https://github.com/dector/Stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/6416809).

Comment: The order of the elements should remain the same, even when two are joined, so this is not a correct solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks! "Correct" problem is easier. __Solution updated.__